# How to make insult command(discord.py)

Tags: api, discord.py, command

i'm making an insult command,its making a JSONDecode Error
any solution...

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def insult(ctx):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
      request = await session.get('https://evilinsult.com/generate_insult.php?lang=en&amp;type=json')
      insultjson = await request.json(content_type='text/html')

  await ctx.send(url=insultjson['insult'])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably the link. Instead of `&amp;`, just use `&`.
Plus, they seem to have a plain text option too - replace `type=json` with `type=text` in the same link and you should be able to use it without having to deal with JSON at all. Check out evilinsult.com's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/EvilInsultGenerator/website)

Also, please always paste your exact errors - it helps us give you a better answer.

Comment: i tried the sol. and its saying
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: @TalhaIqbal if you tried `type=text` I hope you're still not trying to parse it as a JSON. For now, try *only* replacing `&amp;` with `&`